# How can I call the chatgpt api in Google Chrome Extension？

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chatbot, openai-api

I want to make a chrome extension that can call chatgpt api.
But I haven't seen openai open the api.

I see that the corresponding chrome extension implements such technology, such as this blog
https://www.extspy.com/blog/List-of-10-Best-Chatgpt-Chrome-Extensions-for-2023

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you you have tried, share the outcome of you search and research efforts and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: ChatGPT has no API yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fetch API to send a request to the OpenAI API.

You will need to signup for an API key with OpenAI first:
https://openai.com/api/

To send a question to GPT you would make the following Fetch API call.

```
const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/completions', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY'
  },
  body: {
    model: 'text-davinci-003',
    prompt: 'How do I make an API call to OpenAI inside a Chrome Extension?',
    max_tokens: 2000
  }
})

console.log(response.data.choices[0].text)
```

Ref: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions

Comment: ChatGPT has no API yet.

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't but OpenAIs GPT-3 model does. As per the link I put in the answer above. GPT-3 is a very similar model to what is used by ChatGPT

Comment: Incorrect, ChatGPT uses a GPT-3 derived model, but that's not the same model by a stretch. If you're answering a question about "API X" with "API Y", you need to explain what "API X" doesn't exist.